# Matlab Error: expression not a valid target for an assignment

Tags: matlab

Here is the dataset

7

4

(3,7)

(1,5)

(1,5)

(4,3)

(4,4)

(4,5)

(1,6)

```
counter =1;             %Keeps track of number of the present number of hubs
continue = 1;   % 1=true 0=false indicates whether to continue forming new
            %hubs

    while continue
    counter = counter + 1;    % adding new hub
    [m,i]=max(dist);        %m= maximum value in the distance array
                           %i is the location of the maximum value in the
```

[Trying to implement this algorithm](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~nicholas/clustering/singleLink.m)

[Here is the my Full code](http://ideone.com/LKN23E)

```
error

Error: File: kmeans.m Line: 14 Column: 10
The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an     assignment.
```

Comment: @David: MCWE: the line with the error, `continue = 1;`

Comment: Ramseyl, by adding a description above your code, you messed up all the line numbering.  In the future, put comments IN your code, and then show your exact file.  Or at least tell us what line the error is talking about.

Answer (score 1):

`continue` is a keyword, you can't use it as the name of a variable.

This actually is pretty obvious because you chose the right language (octave) when you pasted the code on ideone, and it syntax-colored it correctly for MATLAB and Octave code.